# can't upgrade pip in termux

Tags: pip, termux

```
~ $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

> ERROR: Installing pip is forbidden, this will break the python-pip
> package (termux).

[image]

Comment: If *termux* allows the creation of Python virtual environments, then I recommend you use Python virtual environments, and then maybe you can update *pip* inside the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the fact termux typically uses packages from its own repo rather than provided by PyPI. To update pip you should type:

```
pkg install python-pip
```

Answer (score -1):

linux/Termux Fix

Try to install binary utilities, you may or may not get an error but it seamed like there were some missing dependancies for building wheels in pip and other python installs. install using: pkg install binutils-is-llvm

I also had to use: pip freeze --local | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U

Then update & upgrade

the issue may be with rust, try rustup

also try to install aarch64

also try to install rust

also try to install curl

also try to freeze pip and try updating again.

I was trying to install and upgrade pip in termux and i received many similar errors refering to issues with curl, pip, rust and aarch64, i hope this fixes the issue with pip not upgrading and or installing pythons through pip.